# validate file type in joomla or core php

Tags: file-upload

In joomla or core php when we upload any file it validate only extension on file.

Issue is that when i am changed the extension of an .exe file to pdf/jpg it gets uploaded.
And validation failed.
Can any one tell me how i can put validation for this condition in php or Joomla.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on the "Restrict Uploads" setting in the Options of the Media component, then Joomla will try to check for the real file type. However, please note that the check will fail if you don't have PECL library or the MIME Magic library installed. See [this post](https://www.itoctopus.com/invalid-mime-type-detected-error-when-trying-to-upload-a-pdf-file-in-joomla-media-manager) about this.